# How to declare cell range only with occupied range in excel

Tags: office-interop, excel-interop

I am working on an Excel based C# project where I have to put a whole column of data into a single dimensional array but I am unable to find proper way to do so.

The code I have used is although working but it drops the whole data of a column including unused cells (after the used range of my Excel column) into an array which wastes system resources.
any idea how to achieve this . I have tried the below code .

```
Excel.Range range3 = sheet.get_Range("A:A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to infer the code prior to get the workbook and worksheet but try this ...

```
var lastCell = (Range)xlWorksheet.Range[$"A{xlWorksheet.Rows.Count}"].End[XlDirection.xlUp];
var values = ((Range)xlWorksheet.Range[$"A1:{lastCell.Address}"]).Value;
```

It will find the last **visible** cell in column A and then provide all of the values from A1 down to the last cell into an array.